# New fields work on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently added `image_url` and `pin1` through `pin4` fields to my `blogs` table of my Rails app.

I added them to the schema:

```
 create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "teaser"
    t.text "body"
    t.boolean "published", default: false
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.string "video_url"
    t.bigint "spree_user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "resource_id", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "image_url"
    t.string "pin1"
    t.string "pin2"
    t.string "pin3"
    t.string "pin4"
    t.index ["resource_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_resource_id"
    t.index ["spree_user_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_spree_user_id"
```

I added them to the controller params:

```
   def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(
        :title,
        :teaser,
        :body,
        :image,

        :published,
        :published_at,
        :subcategory_ids,

        :image_url,
        :video_url,
        :pin1,
        :pin2,
        :pin3,
        :pin4,
        :user_id,
        :resource_id,
        :slug
      )
    end
```

And to the form:

```
      <%= form.label :image_url %>
      <%= form.text_field :image_url, class: "form-control" %>

      ...

      <%= form.label "Pinterest Pin Url 1" %>
      <%= form.text_field :pin1, class: "form-control" %>
```

Everything works perfectly and they display on my localhost:

```
    <% if @blog.pin1 %>
      <%= image_tag @blog.pin1, class: "pin shadow-bottom", style: "display: inline-block" %>
    <% end %>
```

But on Heroku the values don't save.  I get no errors, server log or otherwise.  I did `heroku run rake db:migrate` with no errors.

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Comment: You ran the migrations on Heroku after pushing the new migration files up, correct?

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes, I did `heroku run rake db:migrate` and double checked that the appopriate fields came up in `heroku run rails c`.

Comment: @dbugger I added columns to my existing `blog` table, but in a new migration, not a modified one that had already been migrated.

Comment: @dbugger I think that is taken from the `schema.rb` file as proof the update happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect your database a bit with `psql`:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

Once at the SQL prompt, you can look at your table to see if the changes got applied:

```
\d blogs
```

One thing to note is that in production Rails will cache your database schema on application boot, so if you ran your migrations but haven't restarted your application since the migrations were run with `rake db:migrate`, ActiveRecord would not have awareness of the new the fields. You can restart the application with `heroku restart` and then check to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The `heroku restart` thing worked!  It's so ridiculous that I tried so much only to have "turn it off then back on again" fix everything.  Curse you, computers!

Comment: There's an little library I help maintain called [parity](https://github.com/thoughtbot/parity) that you can use to migrate and restart in one command.